# Suppose $Y\sim N(0,X^2)$, and $X\sim Bernoulli(0.5)$ on $\{1,2\}$, how to prove (or rigorously argue) that $X,Y$ are not independent

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose $Y\sim N(0,X^2)$, and $X\sim Bernoulli(0.5)$ on $\{1,2\}$, how to prove (or rigorously argue) that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Can I proceed as follows: try to show that there exists $x$ and $y$ such that $Pr(Y\leq y|x)\neq Pr(Y\leq y)$?

This could be shown as follows:

$Pr(Y\leq y)=0.5\Phi(y)+0.5\Phi(\frac{y}{2})$,

$Pr(Y\leq y|X=1)=\Phi(y)$

Thus $Pr(Y\leq y)-Pr(Y\leq y|X=1)=0.5[\Phi(\frac{y}{2})-\Phi(y)]\neq0$ for $y\neq 0$.

Comment: One way: consider $\Pr(|Y| \le y\mid X)$ for any $y\ne 0.$  More generally, formulated to reveal the basic idea most clearly: let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ have two different distributions and let $Y=Z_X.$ Prove $X$ and $Y$ are not independent by considering an event $\mathcal E$ for which the two probabilities $\Pr(Z_i\in\mathcal E)$ differ: that almost automatically leads to a definition of (non)independence.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, this is extremely helpful! I just updated the question, does the way I do it work too?

Comment: Yes: you have the idea.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much, whuber!

Comment: Situations like this inspire generalizations, which sometimes creates a new understanding or perspective on familiar concepts.  For instance, what happens when $X$ can take on three values? How about when $X$ is continuous?  This encourages us to start thinking of the *marginal* distribution of $Y$ as being a *mixture* of (possibly infinitely many) *conditional distributions* parameterized by $X.$  Herein lies an interesting picture of the interplay among the concepts of joint, marginal, and conditional distributions, mixtures, and independence.

Comment: @whuber Right. Such interplay is really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(|Y| > 1.96\, |\, X = 1) < 0.06,$ but $P(|Y| > 1.96,|\, X = 2) > .32.$ This can be shown using printed normal tables. Illustration by simulation in R below:

```
set.seed(722)
x = sample(1:2, 10^6, rep=T)
y = rnorm(10^6, 0, x)
mean(abs(y[x==1]) > 1.96)
[1] 0.05046732
mean(abs(y[x==2]) > 1.96)
[1] 0.3280174
```

Comment: @Henry. Yes. Thanks. Changed now. (Distracting phone call in the midst of this.)

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.